# How to migrate a project from Linq to SQL to Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, orm

I'm a new junior dev at my company and I've been tasked with migrating a legacy .NET Framework project to .NET Core 6.

While I was looking through the code on this project I noticed that a majority of the queries being done were using `System.Data.Linq` - Linq-to-SQL, which to my understanding is no longer supported in .NET Core.

So my question is: how would I go about converting the project to Entity Framework Core? I noticed that there is a `.DBML` file, which from my research, is the modeling file for Linq to SQL, would the first step be converting this to an `.EDMX` file? Do I even need to do this or should I remove the `.DBML` file and it's associated designer file, then manually edit the classes that it generated?

Is there an easy way to do this is Visual Studio? I know `Mindbox.Data.Linq` exists, but I rather rip the bandage off than keep the dependency on Linq-to-SQL.

This is my first time dealing with EF or ORMs so I greatly appreciate any help or insight you guys can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) from Microsoft regarding upgrading .Net Framework to .Net Core. There is a [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) that can help to upgrade.

Regarding the Linq to SQL, go through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-code).

From my expereince, it really depends on how complex your current project is. In some cases, it might be easier to re-write your code.